# Updating only one of two maps in QGIS Print-Composer without updating other map

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I have two maps within the map composer in qgis. Whenever I want to update one map it updates both maps.

How can I prevent QGIS from updating the other map?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On the map item go to 'Item Properties  >  Layers'.  There are two check boxes:

"Lock Layers" = prevent any layers being added or removed from the map window

"Lock styles for layers" = prevents styles changing on layers visible in the map window.

Checking both of these for a particular map item stop any changes happening to that map so you freely make changes to a different map window.

Answer (score 1):

On Qgis 3.4.4-Madeira you can do it by lock layers and lock style for layers in item properties of the map you want to lock, so every time we change map items or view style it wont be rendered on our map layout.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In the **Item properties** tab, you can disable the `Draw map canvas items` option for your map which should stop it from updating:

[image: Draw map canvas items]

Comment: That's not what that option does - it controls whether or not annotations are shown on the map