# Saving individual figures in Print Composer in QGIS 2

Tags: print-composer, qgis-2

Can anyone tell me how to save individual figures in QGIS print composer that I can later go back and edit?

Do I have to create a new print composer for each figure?

I am using QGIS 2.18.9.

Comment: If I understand your question well then this will be the solution: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207418/how-can-i-update-only-one-map-out-of-two-maps-in-qgis-print-composer-without-upd